# Retrieve user's Skype avatar and profile with Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, skype, botframework

The current Activity gives us the "from" with the ID and Name of the sender.
Is it possible to retrieve the user's avatar and profile information?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible?  Depends on what platform you're talking about, most likely.  Can you be specific?  Have you tried anything so far, on that platform?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not yet supported.

Comment: Is it planned to be soon?

Comment: Can't make any promises with regard to the roadmap, but it is recognized as an important feature

Comment: Really, that is an important feature! 
Can I help you @Lars? The "common devs" could implement and submmit features for review in botframework?

Comment: @Lars Is this feature available now? What is the recommend procedure to get Skype user profile picture/avatar via Bot Framework.